# Reasoning weighted regression via causal inference

Tags: causality, weighted-regression

I want to follow a similar approach to what was done in the paper of Bornkamp et al. in 2021 (DOI: 10.1002/pst.2104). More specifically they added a link to a R markdown file (https://oncoestimand.github.io/princ_strat_drug_dev/princ_strat_example.html) with a working example how to implement the principal stratum strategy. One of their approach was modelling the stratum membership by a logistic regression and the predicted probabilities are then used to adjust a Cox-model by weighting. In the end, they compared the estimated coefficients to other Cox-models.

As said, I want to follow this approache but I want to understand the reasoning for this. In the paper of Bornkamp & Bermann from 2020 (DOI: 10.1080/19466315.2019.1575280) they have quite a nice reasoning for the weighting approach. However, they are not quantifying a regression coefficient but rather a difference in probabilities as
$$
\Delta(t)=P(T(1)>t\mid B(1)=1)-P(T(0)>t\mid B(1)=1)
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(T(0)>t\mid B(1)=1)=&\int P(T(0)>t\mid B(1)=1,Z)p(Z\mid B(1)=1)dZ\\
&\text{Principal ignorability:}\\
=&\int P(T(0)>t\mid Z)p(Z\mid B(1)=1)dZ\\
&\text{Due to randomization:}\\
=&\int P(T(0)>t\mid X=0,Z)p(Z\mid B(1)=1)dZ\\
&\text{Consistency assumption:}\\
=&\int P(T>t\mid X=0,Z)p(Z\mid X=1,B(1)=1)dZ\\
\end{aligned}
$$
What results from this is according to the paper:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p(T(0)\mid B(1)=1)&=\int p(T\mid X=0,Z)p(Z\mid X=1,B(1)=1)dZ\\
&=\int p(T,Z\mid X=0)\frac{p(Z\mid X=1,B(1)=1)}{p(Z\mid X=0)}dZ\\
&=\int p(T,Z\mid X=0)\frac{p(B=1\mid Z,X=1)p(Z\mid X=1)p(X=1)}{p(Z\mid X=0)p(B=1,X=1)}dZ\\
&\text{Due to randomization }p(Z\mid X=1)=p(Z\mid X=0):\\
&\propto \int p(T,Z\mid X=0)\underbrace{p(B=1\mid Z,X=1)}_{w(Z)}dZ
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, they say in the paper that this result can be implemented via modelling for example a weighted Kaplan-Meier, where the weights $w(z)$ are modelled via logistic regression. However, they do not mention anything about integrating over the covariates $Z$. They call this approach "weighted placebo patients".

My problem is that I do not really see the connection between this "weighted placebo patients" approach to the weighted Kaplan-Meier estimator (and thus also do not see the relation to the weighted Cox-model).

Any help to clarify this is much appreciated!